# How to add a MVC Rest API to a Sharepoint 2013 App and how to consume it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

When creating a Sharepoint 2013 App project in Visual Studio you get a project that can be deployed and debugged against a Sharepoint Server.

In that application you have access to a lot of Sharepoint Specific REST API functions that work with the Sharepoint Specific Data (User information, documents, lists, etc.). But what if I now want to add domain specific  functionality that is backed by a specific Database that only contains those domain specific structure and data?

Do I have to set up the asp.net MVC application on an IIS myself and authenticate the calls to the API myself or is there a way to let the API reside in the Sharepoint Web App Domain and be deployed side by side with the Sharepoint App itself?

Or is it even possible to extend the Javascript- and REST API of that specific Sharpoint Installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found a way to add an asp.net MVC web api project to the SharePoint IIS site. I think you need access to the application_start event to set up route rules so that makes it difficult. You can deploy your own wcf or asmx services to the layouts directory. Or you can cheat and create an aspx page that returns JSON data.

I would create my own asp.net web api on a different web application (and domain). You can use CORS to allow cross-site scripting from SharePoint to your custom api. If you go with this approach, the api and SharePoint will have to leverage the same identity provider. So SharePoint's NTLM is no longer an option.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I came to some similar considerations and found out about the CORS and web proxy features. But that authentication issue is actually a problem.

Comment: Why did you propose to create the web api on a different domain? Wouldnt it be easier to let it reside on the same IIS as Sharepoint does? Especially concerning the authentication issues.

Comment: It depends on how you define easier. Like I said, it appears to be impossible to shove in a nice asp.net mvc web api into the SharePoint IIS site. If you cant do that, you have to do wcf, which I don't find easy at all to write and a pain to consume. And I need to change my comment. You can do NTLM with SharePoint and Windows with .net web api.

Comment: So is it more common to simply model the Applications' Services by Sharepoint Lists that point to the specific datasources and access those lists through the default Sharepoint API? I'm struggling do understand that first step towards Sharepoint App Development that go beyond simple sharepoint lists and document libraries.

Comment: It really depends on your need. I think using a list as datasource is more common but it's not always appropriate. A list can easily mimic a simple table with simple relationships. But I'd still use a SQL backend for complex relationships with thousands of rows.

Comment: I have created a webapi on another webserver now and access it through the Sharepoint WebProxy, which works like a charm. Authentication is a bit tricky but not impossible.